# Windows 10 Latest Update - Laravel Valet - Creating Site Links in One Drive

Tags: windows, laravel, onedrive, valet

I've been having issues ever since I updated my Windows 10.
Actually, it happens every time I do a major update for Windows 10.

My Valet Links to sites within OneDrive stopped working.
If I run

`valet links`

I can still see all my site links correctly but going to

`example.test`

gives a "**404 - Not Found**".

I've tested different sites on C Drive, other Drive. The sites work fine.
Only websites that are in my OneDrive folder don't work.

When I run

`valet link site`

I get the following

```
The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive.
A [testSite] symbolic link has been created in [C:/Users/Richard/.config/valet/Sites/testSite].
```

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has had this problem, the way I've resolved it is by doing the following

**1. Uninstall Valet**

```
valet stop
valet uninstall
composer global remove cretueusebiu/valet-windows
```

**2. Uninstall Laravel**

```
composer global remove "laravel/installer"
```

**3. Re-Install XAMPP (Mainly for the updated PHP)**

*I assume updating your PHP installation would give the same end result*

**4. Re-Install Valet**

```
composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows
valet install
```

**5. Re-Install Laravel**

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

**6. Parking and Linking Sites should work again.**

I hope this helps anyone running into the same problem.